# Advantages/disadvantages of virtualizing a CPU?

Tags: linux, windows, cpu, virtualization

I saw that my virtualization tool does not virtualize my CPU. But, it virtualizes everything else. I want to know what could be the reason, advantage/disadvantage of virtualizing a CPU.

Comment: why do you think that your "virtualization tool" does not virtualize the cpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CPU for your VM. Either the real on or an emulated one.

If you mostly use the real CPU then you have the advantage of native performance.

If you virtualise/emulate a CPU then:

1. You gain flexibility (e.g. an AMD/Intel CPU could emulate an ARM or MIPS CPU)
2. But you loose speed since emulation is a lot slower.

Comment: So, in plain terms, a virtualized cpu's instructions need to be translated to the real cpu's instructions, right ? and translation slows execution.

Comment: Hennes ... he so useful

Comment: Translation indeed slows down execution. Sometimes a lot. If you want to test the speed difference on your computer try [Qemu](http://www.qemu.org/‎). It allows you to both emulate a CPU or use the real one.